# Joining two dataframes based on partially matching country names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, fuzzywuzzy

Currently, I have two dataframes that look like the following:

DF1:

| Date | Country | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | The United States | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| 01/02/2020 | The United States | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 01/03/2020 | The United States | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 01/01/2020 | Republic of Korea | 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 01/02/2020 | Republic of Korea | 4 | 5 | 6 |

and DF2:

| Date | Country | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | United States of America | 9.0 |
| 01/02/2020 | United States of America | 9.1 |
| 01/03/2020 | United States of America | 9.4 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 01/01/2020 | South Korea | 2.1 |
| 01/02/2020 | South Korea | 2.5 |

I would like to merge them on 'Country' and 'Date_reported' but the names they use for each individual country can be quite different. I have looked into fuzzywuzzy and some other packages but I can't quite find a merge-like command that will let me do exactly what I want. I am hoping to end up with the following dataframe below (using DF1's country names):

| Date | Country | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | The United States | 0 | 1 | 5 | 9.0 |
| 01/02/2020 | The United States | 2 | 5 | 0 | 9.1 |
| 01/03/2020 | The United States | 1 | 4 | 1 | 9.4 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 01/01/2020 | Republic of Korea | 2 | 3 | 7 | 2.1 |
| 01/02/2020 | Republic of Korea | 4 | 5 | 6 | 2.5 |

Is there an efficient way to do this that doesn't entail me manually switching all of DF2's country names? Thank you for any help you can give me on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can give [`fuzzymatcher`](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzymatcher/#history) a try, but please do keep in mind it may not work on all the cases.

```
# pip install fuzzymatcher
from fuzzymatcher import link_table, fuzzy_left_join

merge_df = fuzzy_left_join(df, df1, ["Country", "Date"], ["Country", "Date"])
merge_df = merge_df[["Date_left", "Country_left", "A", "B", "C", "D"]]

    Date_left   Country_left        A   B   C   D
0   01/01/2020  The United States   0   1   5   9.0
3   01/02/2020  The United States   2   5   0   9.1
4   01/03/2020  The United States   1   4   1   9.4
5   01/01/2020  Republic of Korea   2   3   7   2.1
10  01/02/2020  Republic of Korea   4   5   6   2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of countries that are in df1, but not in df2 as follows:

```
new_list=[]
for country in df1.country.tolist():
    if country not in df2.country.tolist():
        new_list.append(country)
        
new_list
```

Accordingly, you need to change the name of countries in df2. You can do it by creating a dictionary with the countries which are present in new_list.

```
dict={"United States of America":"The United States","Republic of Korea","South Korea"}
df2["Country"].replace(dict, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list=[]
for country in df1.country.unique():
    if country not in df2.country.unique():
        new_list.append(country)
        
new_list
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.